# Publishing from ArcMap to GeoServer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geoserver

I have read few papers to get through the process in GeoServer and still lost at it.

My current situation is, I have a hotspot analysis that is done in ArcMap.

How can I publish it to GeoServer?

Answer (score 1):

Save your heatmap as a GeoTiff (or other raster output) and then [create a new GeoTiff datastore](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/geotiff.html) in GeoServer. You will then be prompted to publish a new layer from that store, click publish and fill in as much or as little metadata as you need. If necessary you can also [style your raster using SLD](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/cookbook/rasters.html).